# If I have Ubuntu installed along side Windows, does the firewall on Windows work along with the antivirus system?

Tags: installation, firewall

I have Ubuntu installed on my Windows 7 computer. I was curious to know if the firewall on that one is activated (I have to turn it on each time I'm on the computer) along with the antivirus system, if not, should I download AVG and Firestarter?

Answer (score 0):

No I don't think so, it is a different operating system so those applications won't startup.  You'll need to install the linux equivalents if you want an anti-virus and firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:
No it won't be activated, but you don't need them.  If you need a firewall, install `gufw` and configure your rules with it.

---

Long Answer:
Windows and Ubuntu are separate entities.  If you are using a dual boot type (or even Wubi), the Windows firewall and antivirus will NOT protect you from viruses.

However, in Ubuntu, there's almost no need for antivirus.  There is no real need for antivirus in Linux because most viruses on the internet are written to target Windows or Mac.  There are very few linux viruses that can affect every Linux operating system out there, so there's really only a very very very tiny chance you'll ever need to be devirusing your Linux.

You should at least configure a firewall, though.  You can start by installing `gufw`, and then add your firewall rules to that.